# Switch Dll Reference to different version at runtime

Tags: c#, autofac, mef

In my .NET Application (.NET Framework 4.8) I am trying to implement an exchange of the implementation of one of my interfaces.

I have got the following project structure:

MyProgram.Exchange:

```
public interface IExchange {
   void DoSomething();
}
```

MyProgram.Exchange.V1 (Reference to Some.dll (Version 1.0.0.0))

```
[Export(typeof(IExchange))]
public class Exchange : IExchange {
   public void DoSomething(){}
}
```

MyProgram.Exchange.V2 (Reference to Some.dll (Version 2.0.0.0))

```
[Export(typeof(IExchange))]
public class Exchange : IExchange {
    public void DoSomething(){}
}
```

In my Startup.cs of my main program I create a DirectoryCatalog and register the Types inside my V1 as default behaviour:

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog($".", $"*V1*.dll");
// ...
var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterComposablePartCatalog(catalog);
```

Initially this works fine. But at some point further inside my Application I need to switch the Reference from V1 to V2.
My Problem now is, that when calling "builder.RegisterComposablePartCatalog(catalog)" I get an exception, because the referenced assembly "Some.dll" is already registered with another version.

Is there a way to completely remove the reference to MyProgram.Exchange.V1 and all its dependencies and register the MyProgram.Exchange.V2 instead.

Sorry if the explanation of the problem isnt the best, but I hope you get my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the case the option is to load assemblies dynamically using custom AppDomain.

You can realize it like:

- create AppDomain`AppDomain.CreateDomain()`
- `Assembly.Load()`
- use instance / register your types using reflection

And when you'll need to replace the dll:

- remove the types from DI registration
- remove the AppDomain `AppDomain.Unload()` (the way to UNLOAD already loaded assemblies)
- load new assemlby and register types using reflection analogically.

Unfortunately, when you reference dll at compile time, there's no option to "unload" it.

Comment: The moment I call the AppDomain.Load() on a custom created AppDomain the main Domain has this Assembly loaded too. 

var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("myDomain");
domain.Load("MyProgram.Exchange.V2");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies(); // contains the Assembly now.

Comment: As I said, you CAN'T load the assembly at compile time (as a refference). You have to get it done by reflection. You have to load the dll using reflection from the very beginning (at application startup?) - to load it to custom domain.